# Can I redirect a page and keep the original pathname?

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-html

I want to have a Tumblr with a landing page that redirects to a page I created.

- Tumblr URL: https://example.tumblr.com
- Page URL: https://example.tumblr.com/landing

I managed to to that with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href == 'https://example.tumblr.com/') location.replace('https://example.tumblr.com/landing');;
</script>
```

But by using this method my Tumblr frontpage gets the page pathname (example.tumblr.com/landing), instead of the orginal URL (example.tumblr.com).

Is there a way to redirect to the landing page but with the original Tumblr URL?

Comment: Unlikely so, without the possibility of modifying the underlying web server's configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) on the landing page

Comment: You might wanna look at htaccess

Comment: you can solve this another way around, either but placing it in the content of your index page, but then only showing it on the index page (using js) or getting the content via ajax. Both methods require js to show/hide the content on the home page and not the other pages.